# verify file errors on batch files

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

So lets say I have the following code in a batch file:

```
Del Build6.log

Ren Build5.log Build6.log

Ren Build4.log Build5.log

Ren Build3.log Build4.log

Ren Build2.log Build3.log

Ren Build.log Build2.log
```

And I want to user Errorlevel to verify the status of each file as an action happens to them, lets say that Build6.log does not exist or it is being used by another program or function. How would I best go about it?

Or should I scrape the whole thing and user Powershell?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754335%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
@break off
@title verify file errors on batch files
@color 0a
@cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Delete Command

if not exist Build6.log (

  echo File "Build6.log" don't exists

) else (

  del Build6.log>nul 2>&1

  if exist Build6.log (
    echo Failure during file deletion
  ) else (
    echo deleted file successfully
  )

)

REM Rename Command

if not exist Build5.log (

  echo File "Build5.log" don't exists

) else (

  ren Build5.log Build6.log>nul 2>&1&if !ErrorLevel! EQU 1 ( echo Failure during file renaming, probably a file with the new name already exists in the directory ) else ( echo File successfully renamed )

)

pause
exit
```

Comment: Can I add something to verify whether a file is in use and not able to be deleted or renamed?

Comment: See, the first command: "del Build6.log>nul 2>&1", after that the file is deleted, the only reason he would not be deleted is if it is in use, if this occurs the message will appear "Failure During file deletion", the same goes for the second command in the example I showed, ", runs the command to rename the file if the ERRORLEVEL is equal to 1 because it failed, and the only reason to fail in the process of renaming the file that already exists is a new file with the new name you defined.

Comment: Only batch with and without help of external tools that I know of no way of knowing if the file is in use, the way I know this is that I showed.

Comment: Is there a way to show if the file is locked for whatever reason?

Comment: As with batch script not there only way to know if a file or directory is locked, is using some external tool, you looking here on the forum and found similar topics explain how to use external tools.